# dpkg errors in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, grub2, dpkg

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up udev (229-4ubuntu21.1) ...
addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: warning: script 'K10runmbbservice' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'runmbbservice' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service runmbbservice if started
insserv: There is a loop between service runmbbservice and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service runmbbservice and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service runmbbservice at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up grub-common (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: warning: script 'K10runmbbservice' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'runmbbservice' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service runmbbservice if started
insserv: There is a loop between service runmbbservice and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service runmbbservice and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service runmbbservice at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package grub-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub2-common:
 grub2-common depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub2-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-bin:
 grub-efi-amd64-bin depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64:
 grub-efi-amd64 depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.
 grub-efi-amd64 depends on grub2-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16); however:
  Package grub2-common is not configured yet.
 grub-efi-amd64 depends on grub-efi-amd64-bin (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16); however:
  Package gruNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                       No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                               b-efi-amd64-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi:
 grub-efi depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.
 grub-efi depends on grub-efi-amd64 (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16); however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of os-prober:
 os-prober depends on grub-common; however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package os-prober (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.10) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
 grub-common
 grub2-common
 grub-efi-amd64-bin
 grub-efi-amd64
 grub-efi
 os-prober
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
that is the output when i use sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of `sudo apt-get intall -f`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster just guessing (grub + initrd ?= /boot size problems). But, let's wait OP for full output. Retracted vote.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Recently I installed software for Huawei 3G-modem/card **mbbservice**
This helped to solve my Upbuntu 16.10 upgrade:

```
sudo rm -v /etc/rc*/*runmbbservice
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```